# py2exe os.chdir()

Tags: python, path, py2exe

When I was building my program in Python, every file that the program needs was in the root folder, but I decided to re-organise the files in folders, so I create a folder "images" to storage here the favicon and the other images that the program use.
I use os.chdir() to move through the images folder and define the image element, like this.

```
#other code
actualdir = os.getcwd()
imgdir = actualdir + "\images\\"
os.chdir(imgdir)
mywindow.iconbitmap('favicon.ico')
os.chdir(actualdir)
#othercode
```

Ok, so, if I run the program with the Python interpreter, there aren't any problems with this, but, for this program I need to compile an exe version.
I use py2exe to solve this issue, and when I run the exe I got this error on the log file.

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:
'C:\\MyProgram\\Version1.0\\images\\'
```

And it's logical that it can't find the file cause the path is incorrectly defined, using two bars instead of one, but, why my program gives this response, using two bars. The function gives the path and it uses, why is this happened?

Hope something could help me.

Comment: The "two bars" are just the way Python escapes the backslash escape character in strings. In this case it just means the string contains `'C:\MyProgram\Version1.0\images\'`—which seems correct based on what you've described.

Comment: Ok, I know, but what can I do to solve this issue?
Actually, when I run the exe result of the py2exe, it gives me this error, error that the python interpreter don't give.

Comment: I don't think you understand: `>>> 'a\\b' == r'a\b'` outputs
`True`

Comment: You might be able to extract the directory  from `__file__`—although I don't know if it will be right in py2exe.

Comment: The cause for the exception is that you are using a relative path in your code, that isn't correct when cwd is `'C:\\MyProgram\\Version1.0'`. You'll have to copy the image directory or use an absolute path.

Comment: Your code is assuming what the cwd is, which is not always what you think. Sounds like you might need use a configuration file to store the path of the images if you cannot locate them relative to something of which you know the location (like the .py or .exe file).